# ASP.NET MVC: Passing context to a custom class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What's the best way of passing context to a custom business/helper class from an action method? The helper/business class that i'm creating will need information such as the currently logged in user, an instance of a UrlHelper class (to generate urls) and any other data that's related to ASP.NET MVC's infrastructure.

I was thinking of just passing the instance of a controller. Is this advisable? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The helper/business class that i'm creating will need information such as the currently logged in user.

Unlikely. IMHO It will suffice the username => User.Identity.Name, which could be passed as a string parameter to this business tier.

> an instance of a UrlHelper class (to generate urls)

Unlikely. Generating urls is not the responsibility of the business tier. Pass the urls directly from the controller which has an [Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.url.aspx) property allowing you to generate urls at free will (again as string parameters).

Conclusion: decouple your business logic from your infrastructure. Basically if you are calling something a business logic the sole notion of *URL helper* hardly makes sense. Once you cross the boundaries of the web tier there are no more url helpers.

Comment: I like your answer. What if my class is a helper class that contains mostly application/UI logic that communicates to a web service that contains the business logic. Is it then okay for the helper class to be coupled with ASP.NET MVC's infrastructure?

Comment: @burnt1ce, yes, if it is a helper class (HtmlHelper, UrlHelper, ...) it is perfectly fine to be coupled with the ASP.NET MVC infrastructure and pass the required information to the business layer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can I do the same with view models? For some of my view models, i would like to pass in the controller context and business entity to the constructor of the view model.

Comment: @burnt1ce, I wouldn't do this with view models. I would use a mapping layer and prepare everything in advance so that the view models already have the right form for the view.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce coupling pass value types or parameter/dto classes that already exist in your business helper layer.

Don't pass anything related to the Web/UI tier.